# Input error: Expected '--nodes' to have at least 1 valid item, but had 0 []

Tags: csv, import, neo4j, path, filepath

I've read plenty of articles about this issue on here, but I still can't seem to get around this issue.  I've been trying to use Neo4j-import on some large genome data CSVs I have, but it doesn't seem to recognise the files. My command line input is as follows:

```
user@LenovoPC ~/.config/Neo4j Desktop/Application/neo4jDatabases/database-2f182948-e170-45b1-b9f4-19d236ff5d43/installation-3.5.1 $ \
bin/neo4j-import --into data/databases/graph.db --id-type string \
--nodes:Allele variants.csv --nodes:Chromosome chromosome.csv --nodes:Phenotype phenotypes.csv \
--nodes:Sample samples.csv --relationships:BELONGS_TO variant_chromosomes.csv \
--relationships: sample_phenotypes.csv --relationships:ALTERNATIVE_TO variant_variants.csv \
--relationships:HAS sample_variants50-99.csv.gz
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
WARNING: neo4j-import is deprecated and support for it will be removed in a future version of Neo4j; please use neo4j-admin import instead.
Input error: Expected '--nodes' to have at least 1 valid item, but had 0 []

Caused by:Expected '--nodes' to have at least 1 valid item, but had 0 []
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected '--nodes' to have at least 1 valid item, but had 0 []
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.util.Validators.lambda$atLeast$6(Validators.java:144)
    at org.neo4j.helpers.Args.validated(Args.java:670)
    at org.neo4j.helpers.Args.interpretOptionsWithMetadata(Args.java:637)
    at org.neo4j.tooling.ImportTool.extractInputFiles(ImportTool.java:623)
    at org.neo4j.tooling.ImportTool.main(ImportTool.java:445)
    at org.neo4j.tooling.ImportTool.main(ImportTool.java:380)
```

I included the file path, as I'm using Neo4j Desktop and am not sure if this has a different file structure?  My csv files are stored in the import folder (but I also have copies in the current folder and the graph.db folder just in case).

The import directory is as follows:

```
user@LenovoPC ~/.config/Neo4j Desktop/Application/neo4jDatabases/database-2f182948-e170-45b1-b9f4-19d236ff5d43/installation-3.5.1/import $ dir
chromosomes.csv        samples.csv          variants.csv
phenotypes.csv         sample_variants50-99.csv.gz  variants.csv.gz
sample_phenotypes.csv  variant_chromosomes.csv      
variant_variants.csv
```

I can only assume that it's my filepath, but I've tried quite a few alternatives and had no luck at all.  If anyone could shed some light on what the issue is, I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Yes make sure to quote all files and paths that have spaces.

Comment: And this one is odd: `--relationships:` leave off the colon if you have the rel-type in the file

Comment: do you have the files in the local directory? can you add a file listing of that directory? I also think it will create the database local to your current directory, not sure if it supports the nested path there.

Comment: is it perhaps just a typo
e.g. your file is called `chromosome_s_.csv` but you use `chromosome.csv` without the s

Comment: please also check the other files for exact spelling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best is to cd into the desktop directory, place the csv files into the import folder.

then you can do:

```
cd ~/.config/Neo4j Desktop/Application/neo4jDatabases/database-2f182948-e170-45b1-b9f4-19d236ff5d43/installation-3.5.1

bin/neo4j-import --into data/databases/graph.db --id-type string \
--nodes:Allele import/variants.csv \
--nodes:Chromosome import/chromosome.csv \
--nodes:Phenotype import/phenotypes.csv \
--nodes:Sample import/samples.csv \
--relationships:BELONGS_TO import/variant_chromosomes.csv \
--relationships import/sample_phenotypes.csv \
--relationships:ALTERNATIVE_TO import/variant_variants.csv \
--relationships:HAS import/sample_variants50-99.csv.gz
```

Some more notes:

- HAS is a pretty generic relationship type
- I left off the colon here: `--relationships import/sample_phenotypes.csv` not sure if you have the rel-type in the file
- is this a single file? `--relationships:HAS import/sample_variants50-99.csv.gz`

Comment: `sample_variants` is a single file, but an initial test of samples 50-99 out of ~2,000.  The rel-type is in `sample_phenotypes` under the header `type`, but the type varies for different rows.

Comment: The terminal was opened from the installation directory, so I think this opens up in the same directory anyway?